# How to prevent jobs from running when pushing tags and when branch is a specific one with rules

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm a bit confused with the Gitlab I syntax.

I have some jobs that I don't want to trigger when I simply push tags like

```
git tag -a 1.0.0 -m "Added version 1.0.0"
git push --tags
```

The following works correctly, as this job is not being triggered for above scenario

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test
    expire_in: 8 hour
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never  
    - when: always
```

Now I also have jobs with a rule to run conditionally depending on whether the commit branch is stable (i.e: `main`) or not.
Like this one

```
package_beta:
  stage: publish
  variables:
    PACKAGE_UNSTABLE_SUFFIX: beta
  before_script:
    - mkdir $PACKAGE_OUTPUT_DIR
  script:
    - dotnet pack *.sln --configuration Release --output $PACKAGE_OUTPUT_DIR --version-suffix $PACKAGE_UNSTABLE_SUFFIX --include-source --include-symbols
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - $PACKAGE_OUTPUT_DIR/
    expire_in: 8 hour
```

The above also works well. The problem is when I want to have several conditions in rules, like: **I want my job to run only when branch is not main AND ALSO when the push is not a tag commit**. How to do that with rules?

Here is the problem.

This does not work. It will actually run the job even when the branch is `main`.

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    when: never
```

This does not work either

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    when: never
  - when: always
```

Comment: Use `&&` for combining conditions: `- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG`

Comment: See here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#join-variable-expressions-together-with--or-

Comment: Thanks, 
```if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null```
did the trick to skip job if the branch is not main and also if the commit is a tags push

Comment: Note: this question has nothing to do with Git; GitLab's CI runner is not part of Git, but rather a value-add add-on that GitLab provide.

Comment: Just to add further clarity, multiple `if` clauses will explicitly be interpreted as `this OR that`. There is no way (as of current Gitlab version) to interpret these as AND's. You can only use AND's within a single `if` clause. This is the only way to build complex conditionals with `()` as well.